# C# Add random numbers from an array in a ListBox

Tags: c#, timer

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        dizi[i] = rnd.Next(10, 25);
        Form2 child = new Form2();
    }
```

I've been trying to create a program that will add numbers one by one (hence the timer) to a listbox in a child form. Form1 is the parent form and Form2 is the child form. What am I missing here?

Comment: what the issue here?

Comment: You likely don't want to create a new child form every tick. You'll also need some code to add the number to the listbox...

Comment: what is `i` and why are you creating a new instance of `new Form2()` each tick?

Comment: Create the `Random` object as a field in the class rather than creating it new for each timer tick.

Comment: You shouldn't declare a new instance of `Random` each time. Make that a class-level field. And the line that declares a new instance of `Form2` is not doing anything.

Comment: I want to create a number generator that will generate numbers between 10 and 25. They should appear in the listbox of the child form (Form2), I used a timer in Form1.cs (parent form) to make them appear one by one, not at the same time. How can I create this and add the numbers to the listbox?

Comment: In `Form1` you should have class-level references to `Form2` and `rnd`. The `form2.ListBox1` instance should be made public. Then you would just do `form2.ListBox1.Items.Add(rnd.Next(10, 26);`

Comment: How do I make the listbox public? When I try to access it in Form1, either it doesn't know what listBox1 is or in the code you just sent, form2 does not contain a definition

Comment: @RufusL "class-level field"? Why not application-level, so one instance of Random per whole application

Comment: @Joelty How do you declare an application-level instance? What does that mean?

Comment: ``public static random`` in EntryPoint/Main or class that's dedicated to access random from anywhere in the project aint way to go?

Comment: @Joelty Oh, got you. Thought you meant declare it outside of a class.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this and it works fine...
I put that in the button1_Click function.
Every time I press the button it adds a random number between 10 and 25 to the Box.
It should help you.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
            List<int> dizi = new List<int>();
            dizi.Add(rnd.Next(10, 25));

            foreach (var vari in dizi)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(vari);
            }
```

Comment: This is useful, thanks. But parent form does not know listBox1, it simply doesn't exist in the current context. How to overcome this?

Comment: @Caysle declare it as `public`